# Why is GSI creation so slow?

Tags: couchbase

Running a single node server on a 16GB memory machine. The index creation takes about 18-20 seconds on a bucket with ~70000 documents. The same index on a bucket with 0 documents is taking about 10-12 seconds. Is this normal?
I want to understand the internals of index creation process; if someone can explain or point me to some resource, it'll be of great help. Thank you.

Comment: What kind of index? Is this a SQL++ index, a Full Text Search index, or Analytics index?

Comment: Responded on https://www.couchbase.com/forums/t/why-is-index-creation-so-slow/37729

Comment: @MatthewGroves It's a SQL++ index